# Asp.net Windows Authentication Deny Anonymous Access

Tags: asp.net, windows, authentication

When I RDP to the web server (customer) I enter my user name as domain/username. Which tells me that I am in the AD.
I set the web.config authentication mode="Windows" and Authorization deny="?" (my understanding is that this means deny all who are not authenticated by Windows.)
Then I am trying to open a test page (test.aspx).  And I get Access Denied.
If I set the Authorization to allow users="*", the page opens. But the environment.UserDomainName returns "IIS APPPOOL".  And I would like to see that the environment.UserDomainName would return actual domain name.
What do I need to do? Or what am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current logged in user IIS returning DefaultAppPool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29400373/get-current-logged-in-user-iis-returning-defaultapppool)

Comment: I can't seem to get the current user name.  I can get the domain name.

I get the domain name as follows (works):
    Environment.UserDomainName;

But when I try to get the user name (all methods below), I get the server name instead of the user name:

     Environment.UserName;
     System.Environment.UserName;
     Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME");


The web.config has:
     <authentication mode="Windows" /> 
     <identity impersonate="true" />  or "false", make no difference.
The site in IIS has Windows Authentication and Anonymous Authentication set to Enable.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question, you are trying to get the current user. If so you can use something like this:

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Comment: The following line actually gives me the logged user name:
    HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;

Other important setting should be:
In web.config:

    <identity impersonate="false" />  
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <deny users="?" />  

Thank you.

PS I wish I could understand how to make the code appear as the code.

Comment: According to your other comment you wanted to get the current username. That was the question I was answering. Now your original question was getting the user domain name. It seems you have achieved both, now. 

So now you are looking for certain settings that will stop the Access Denied issue?

Comment: I will reply to your question once I learn how to show a code in the comment.  I want to show the code but it all comes out as text.

Comment: If you want to post code use the back tick ( the key under the ESC key) at the beginning and the end of your code. Like this: `string s = "testing";`.

Comment: In my code I was looking for find email address of a user bases on domain account name.
Here is the code:
`string CurrentUserDomain = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, CurrentUserDomain);
            if (user != null)
            {
               lblEmail.Text = user.EmailAddress;
            }`
Thank you for the suggestion with the back tick.  Too bad I can't figure out how to make each line appear on a separate line.

Comment: Also, the key to making the above code to work was to have the following set in the web.config:
`<identity impersonate="false" />  
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<deny users="?" />  `